# Problem on WooCommerce admin - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function date() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

Since yesterday I have an error message in my admin woocommerce:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function date() on null - on line 524

Here is the problem code in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'bbloomer_admin_products_date_column', 11 );
 
function bbloomer_admin_products_date_column( $columns ){
    
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column ){
        $new_columns[$key] =  $columns[$key];
        if( $key === 'product_cat' )
            $new_columns['modified_date'] = __( 'Last Modified date','woocommerce');
    } 
    return $new_columns;

}

add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'bbloomer_admin_products_date_column_content', 10, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_admin_products_date_column_content( $column, $product_id ){
    
     global $product;
    
    if ( $column == 'modified_date' ) {
       $date=$product->get_date_modified()->date('F j, Y');
      echo $date;
    }
}
```

The ligne 524 is this one: $date=$product->get_date_modified()->date('F j, Y');

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this function? (it was working correctly before)

Comment: `global $product;` is not available there you'll have to get the product object from the function, like this `$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );`

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns', 'bbloomer_admin_products_date_column', 11);

function bbloomer_admin_products_date_column($columns) {

    $new_columns = array();
    foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
        $new_columns[$key] = $columns[$key];
        if ($key === 'product_cat') {
            $new_columns['modified_date'] = __('Last Modified date', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}

add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'bbloomer_admin_products_date_column_content', 10, 2);

function bbloomer_admin_products_date_column_content($column, $product_id) {

    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    if ($column == 'modified_date') {
        $date = $product->get_date_modified()->date('F j, Y');
        echo $date;
    }
}
```